# Find position in array of strings in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, match

I have an array of strings `"alpha", "beta"...` and I'd like to test another string `string2` against this to return 1, if `string2` = `"alpha"`, 2 if it equals `"beta"` etc.

I could do this if it were Excel using `application.match`, but this doesn't exist in Word.

The end goal is to return the unicode value for the appropriate Greek letter from the name of the letter, so if there's a better way of doing it, I'm open to suggestions. Maybe I've been writing too much python, and lists seem like the easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array and test each value against the searched value.

Here's some pseudo code to get you started.

```
Dim greek() As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim searchString As String
Dim match As Integer

For x = LBound(greek) To UBound(greek)
    If greek(x) = searchString Then
        match = x
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: The old ways are still the best sometimes, I should have thought of doing it that way.